# Disable notifications sounds and vibration when app is used

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, notifications

In my iphoneapp in xcode:
What i want to do is disable the sound of notifications coming in from other apps when my app is open. I hope vibration can be disabled the same way. 
Notification can still show up.

The problem is that i want to keep a sound playing without being interrupted by notification sounds.

But until now i have no idea where to get this to happen and if it is even possible.
I do know how to let it interrupt and start again after the interrupting sound has ended.

So any ideas are welcome!

Comment: the thing i want is shown in the Smule® Magic Guitar® app.
When playing, notifications that come in don't disturb the sound of the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set an appropriate Audio Session Category to achieve this. If you have a look at [Choosing the Best Category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html) in this Audio Session guide, you'll probably want to use one of the recording related categories.

Once you've chosen the appropriate category, you should read [Setting and Changing Your Audio Session](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW8) to learn how to actually set the category for you app.